# Python - copies Bad indent

Tags: python, json, formatting

need a bit of help here

I have a python script that copies and edits over txt files 
but I'm having an issue with the indent 
and I am not sure how to repair it

The indent I normally use is `indent=4` and for the most part it has never failed 
Now I am working on smaller files and the files have different indents so when it copies over the file for editing it removed 2 rows

the original file starts with 6 indents and increases and decreases as it continues

Here is the original look

```
{
......"unid": 100,            - indent 6
      "awar": false,
      "upst": [
........{                     - indent 8
.........."lvls": [           - indent 10
............{                 - indent 12
.............."ulpf": true,   - indent 14
              "fsg": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "nupl": {
        "txt": "",
        "cpf": true
      },
      "esup": false,
      "elcl": 0,
      "gacp": false,
      "paid": 5214,
      "lzsid": 24434,
      "livid": 214867,
      "isra": false
    }
```

Here is the Results

```
Top of Market
{
...."unid": 1,            - indent 4
    "awar": false,
    "upst": [
........{                     - indent 8
............"lvls": [           - indent 12
................{
                    "ulpf": true,   - indent 16
                    "fsg": [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "nupl": {
        "txt": "Marks1",
        "cpf": true
    },
    "esup": false,
    "elcl": 0,
    "gacp": false,
    "paid": 125,
    "lzsid": 24434,
    "livid": 214867,
    "isra": false
}, 
Bottom of Market
```

So when I increase the indent to 6 it places all the codes in the right spots but now this section  also increase by 2

this is the result with 6

```
Top of Market
{
      "unid": 1,
      "awar": false,
      "upst": [
            {
                  "lvls": [
                        {
                              "ulpf": true,  --- as you can see here it's moved over a ton
                              "fsg": [   moved over 24 indents
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0
                              ]
                        }
                  ]
            }
      ],
      "nupl": {
            "txt": "Marks1",
            "cpf": true
      },
      "esup": false,
      "elcl": 0,
      "gacp": false,
      "paid": 125,
      "lzsid": 24434,
      "livid": 214867,
      "isra": false
}, 
Bottom of Market
```

what is the best way to fix this problem

Here is the script

```
import shutil
import glob
import json
import re
import asyncio
import sys
from asyncore import loop

unit_to_paid = {"(1)": 125,
                "(2)": 124}

async def update_file(file, arg):
    f = open(file, "r")
    text = f.read()


    data = json.loads(text)
    num = re.search(r"\(([^()]+)\)", file)


    data["unid"] = int(num.group(1))
    data["paid"] = unit_to_paid[num.group(0)]
    data["nupl"]["txt"] = f'Marks{num.group(1)}'

    f.close()

    f = open(file, "w")
    f.truncate(0)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)   ------ here is the indent
    f.write(", \nBottom of Market")
    f.close()

    f1 = open(file, "r+")
    content = f1.read()
    f1.seek(0, 0)
    f1.write("Top of Market" + '\n' + content)
    f1.close()


async def get_update_files(arg):
    # Recursively grabs the files
    files = glob.glob('New folder 2/**/*.txt', recursive=True)

    # Creates a list of tasks to run concurrently
    tasks = []
    for file in files:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(update_file(file, arg)))

    t = asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return t


def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    # Deletes New folder 2 if it exists
    shutil.rmtree('New folder 2', ignore_errors=True)

    # Copies existing files into New folder 2
    shutil.copytree('New folder 1', 'New folder 2')

    # Will get each file and update them concurrently
    if len(args) == 0:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_update_files("all"))
    else:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_update_files(args[0]))

main()
```

I have tried a few things but nothing works I even removed this section so to edit the originals

```
# Deletes New folder 2 if it exists
        shutil.rmtree('New folder 2', ignore_errors=True)
    
        # Copies existing files into New folder 2
        shutil.copytree('New folder 1', 'New folder 2')
```

and updated this `files = glob.glob('New folder 1/**/*.txt', recursive=True)`

Updated result

```
Empty row
Empty row
Empty row
Empty row
Empty row
Empty row ......................1000 indents................ Top Market  
{
        ......"unid": 1,
              "awar": false,
              "upst": [
        ........{
        .........."lvls": [
        ............{
        .............."ulpf": true,
                      "fsg": [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "nupl": {
                "txt": "",
                "cpf": true
              },
              "esup": false,
              "elcl": 0,
              "gacp": false,
              "paid": 5214,
              "lzsid": 24434,
              "livid": 214867,
              "isra": false
         } < this shifted over with 0 indents
```

Comment: Could you clarify the problem a bit more?  Why do you need to exactly replicate the old (inconsistent) indentation?  Whitespace in a JSON file fundamentally does not matter.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can generate the file with indent=4 and then add two spaces at the start of all lines which begin with a space, it will make the first indent equal to 6, while preserving the relative indent of 4 for all subsequent indents.

Comment: @0x5453 - the exact image needs to be do to how it is inserted mostly a look, I am aware with Json the indents does not matter, but a cosmetic look is how we have all are files right now, every file is 100% exact and since we are going to update the files, we wanted them to remain with the same look

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov - the original starts with `indent 0 {` and then the next line of codes starts with 6, and then it increases to more, and then near the end goes back down to 6 again, Now since we are dealing with 100,000 files, the script needs to be able to duplicate the original files exactly the same, Now when I add 6, it corrects every code except the center parts of the file as you can see on my 2nd result, I have a batch script that has been doing the job just fine, but to run 100K files with batch takes way to long, and with batch it copies files exactly

Comment: So once again its a desire look that we have been maintaining for a long time, but as time go by my file counts keep increase, I first started with 20K, then 40K, now I'm pushing 100K plus and my batch is way to slow for this task, and since I already have hundreds of thousands of files in the original look, I would like to keep it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't express myself clear enough in the comment. My idea is first to generate the file with the indent=2, it will give the result:

```
{
.."unid": 100,            - indent 2
  "awar": false,
  "upst": [
....{                     - indent 4
......"lvls": [           - indent 6
........{                 - indent 8
.........."ulpf": true,   - indent 10
          "fsg": [
            0,
```

And after that you add 4 more spaces to all the lines which already start with a space (it excludes lines containing `{` and `}` at the start, so they are not shifted):

```
{
......"unid": 100,            - indent 2 + 4 = 6
      "awar": false,
      "upst": [
........{                     - indent 4 + 4 = 8
.........."lvls": [           - indent 6 + 4 = 10
............{                 - indent 8 + 4 = 12
.............."ulpf": true,   - indent 10 + 4 = 14
              "fsg": [
                0,
```

**UPDATE**

Also, it is not effective to open/read/close the same file multiple times, it's better to read the content once, format it as expected and write the result back. Here is an example how you can modify your
update_file method to achieve this:

```py
async def update_file(file, arg):
    f = open(file, "r+")
    text = f.read()

    data = json.loads(text)

    num = re.search(r"\(([^()]+)\)", file)

    data["unid"] = int(num.group(1))
    data["paid"] = unit_to_paid[num.group(0)]
    data["nupl"]["txt"] = f'Marks{num.group(1)}'
    # Format the json into a string with indent 2
    s = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
    # Replace the starting space on each line with 5 spaces
    # This effectively adds 4 to all indents
    s = re.sub(r'^ ', r'     ', s, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    # Add the header and the footer
    s = "Top of Market\n" + s + ", \nBottom of Market"

    # Replace the file's content with the updated json
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
```

When I run this code on your input I get the following output:

```json
Top of Market
{
      "unid": 1,
      "awar": false,
      "upst": [
        {
          "lvls": [
            {
              "ulpf": true,
              "fsg": [
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "nupl": {
        "txt": "Marks1",
        "cpf": true
      },
      "esup": false,
      "elcl": 0,
      "gacp": false,
      "paid": 125,
      "lzsid": 24434,
      "livid": 214867,
      "isra": false
}, 
Bottom of Market
```

Comment: OH got it OK let me try that - I will have to edit my extraction tool to extract as 2

Comment: When I use 6 all code appear to be correct but the section around the `lvls:` this still shift real bad - so the 2 indent didn't work

Comment: My extraction tool does not adjust for the indent, so I have no way to alter that, with out having to fully edit that script for that, Love your idea, but will not work

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "the section around the lvls: still shifts real bad". I updated the answer with some code and the results of execution of this code. For me it looks correctly.

Comment: Thank you when I tried to shift the indent by 2 the `ulpf` and all the zero increase every time by 6 to 10 indents, Now I see how you updated, and it works, but I'm getting 2 mistakes the top market ends up with like 1000 indents, the whole script seems to work right, not sure if you get that or not, but I end up with 7 empty rows and the Top Market found all the way to the right I end up with a scroll bar, I will update the result I got with the updated code

Comment: I made some minor changes, and got everything right, now I can't figure out the extra blank rows it gives me - `s = re.sub(r'^', r'     ', s, 0, re.MULTILINE)` I removed the space here `r'^'` and this `s = "\nTop of Market\n"` now everything is almost right

Comment: I did this because of the extra rows that appear `s = "\nTop of Market\n"`

Comment: I was certain I posted another comment - but I found how to fix the problem, your update does work but I had to remove and add a few lines  to the script to fix the extra rows with white spaces it was giving me

Comment: It's great that you managed to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Python's standard `json` module, like most JSON encoders, doesn't offer fine control over whitespace. If you need that, then you probably can't use `json.dump`, at least for the entirety of `data`. Instead, write your own code to produce the JSON you want, falling back on `json.dump` for subcomponents when you can.